# VB.NET Background Worker doesn't execute crystal report viewer report source

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

My problem is background worker in vb.net doesn't allow a line of code to execute
here is the code:

```
  Private _worker As BackgroundWorker

Public Sub startload(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    _worker = New BackgroundWorker()
    AddHandler _worker.DoWork, AddressOf WorkerDoWork
    AddHandler _worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted

    _worker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Public Sub WorkerDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    objRpt = New CRBooks
    con.ConnectionString = ConnStr.Connstring
    Dim query As String = CreateSelectQueryAndParameters()
    'if there is no item select, then exit from the method.
    If Not query.Contains("Column") Then
        MessageBox.Show("No selection to display!")
        Return
    End If
    Try
        Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, con)
        Dim Ds As Books = New Books
        adapter.Fill(Ds, "Books")
        objRpt.SetDataSource(Ds)
        MsgBox(Ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0))
        frmReports.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
    Catch oleEx As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(oleEx.Message)
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub WorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

The line frmReports.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt doesn't execute but when i tried to breakpoint the compiler runs the line but doesn't execute.

Comment: what you actually want to acheive.you want to view that report??

Comment: Yes. but it doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have specified the report source for the crystal report viewer,but to view that reportviewer you should call show method of the corresponding form containing the report viewer to view that report.

**use this code.**

```
Public Sub WorkerDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    objRpt = New CRBooks
    con.ConnectionString = ConnStr.Connstring
    Dim query As String = CreateSelectQueryAndParameters()
    'if there is no item select, then exit from the method.
    If Not query.Contains("Column") Then
        MessageBox.Show("No selection to display!")
        Return
    End If
    Try
        Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, con)
        Dim Ds As Books = New Books
        adapter.Fill(Ds, "Books")
        objRpt.SetDataSource(Ds)
        MsgBox(Ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0))
        frmReports.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
        frmReports.CrystalReportViewer1.Refreshreport()
        frmReports.show()
    Catch oleEx As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(oleEx.Message)
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

here `frmReports.show` shows form which contains the reportviewer.

Comment: Frmreports is already open. but i also tried that but there was a runtime error.

Comment: k can you please remove or comment that msgbox and try executing?

Comment: and also try adding `frmReports.CrystalReportViewer1.Refreshreport() `after specifying report source.edited my answer including that.

Comment: an error popped up Refresh is disabled.(RCIWINFORMVIEWR00000005)

Comment: try frmReports.CrystalReportViewer1.Update()...notify me if that too gives error.

Comment: There were no errors but the same thing happened report is not loaded in the viewer.

Comment: is the reportviewer loading?? or it is also nor showing up?

Comment: the report viewer doesn't load, it is already open, because the form that is running the code above is on a different form.